# Session scope in portlet

Tags: session, liferay, portlet, portal

> Session attributes are scoped only to the current action request and following render requests and, must be cleaned up when the portlet receives next action request.If you don’t code it properly, you might end up retaining lot of unused objects in the session, thus causing performance issues<

so does each new action initiates a new session or what? can't I use same session attribute across my whole app ?

Comment: It's hard to understand the intention of the quote without its context. As far as I understand the writer wanted to express: _**If** session attributes are scoped only to the current action request and following render requests, **they** must be cleaned up when the portlet receives the next action request._ By the way, such kind questions are off topic on stackoverflow (as long as you don't quote a common resource like an API reference).

Comment: actually it was an article on a web site ... but your answer seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

The `session scoped` attributes are available until the `PortletSession` is destroyed and there is only one `PortletSession` all the time. The problem with storing attributes in the session is, that they don't clean themselves like attributes in the `RenderRequest` or `ActionRequest`. So if you store a big ammount of attributes in the `PortletSession` you'll get performance issues. I think that's what your quote is about.